# Push notification stopped work after new release (Flutter & FireBase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

Working with Flutter release mode and FireBase for push notifications.
While building new release, the push notifications stopped working.
They used to work on the previous release.
What may be the problem?

Comment: Note that I am using my own backend